# Web api set name and password to request.BasicAuth

Tags: api, authentication, go

The route for login authenticate -- `app.Handle("GET", "/v1/users/token", u.Token)`.

We can get name and password from request.BasicAuth.

```
func (u *User) Token(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params map[string]string) error {
    ...
    name, pass, ok := r.BasicAuth()
    ...
}
```

But how can I set name and pass from client web url?

Answer (score 1):

Before a browser asks the user to supply basic auth credentials, you have to deny the request access (using status code 401 Unauthorized). You should set the header `WWW-Authenticate` to `Basic realm="Your message"`. 
Also see [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).

So in your code, when `ok` is false, you should deny that request:

```
func (u *User) Token(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params map[string]string) error {
    ...
    name, pass, ok := r.BasicAuth()
    if !ok  {
         w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Your message\"")
         http.Error(w, "Must supply authentication credentials", http.StatusUnauthorized)
         return
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that mean I should set name and pass in client header, then send the `/v1/users/token` url?

Comment: Correct. The example checks if the client sent the credentials (in that case `ok` would be true). If not, the request is denied